# Text size in Quasar input field

Tags: quasar-framework

I have a text box for a ten-digit phone number. The box is 300px wide and the font looks small and condensed.

How can I increase both the font size and spacing in the QInput component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:input-style="{ fontSize: '35px' }"`

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/abGGgqb

Comment: :input-style="{ fontSize: '20px', letterSpacing: '10px', textAlign: 'center' }"